# Прерывание функции по истечению времени ожидания

Tags: c

Есть ли способ ограничить время ожидания у блокирующих функций, например таких, как  `getch()`?

Comment: В языке нет. Средствами ОС, конечно (засвисит от ОС)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> время ожидания у блокирующих функций

Есть разные блокирующие функции...

Например, функция *select* имеет возможность отслеживать таймаут.

Функции *getch* не существует вообще. Есть *getc()* и *getchar()*. Обе они блокирующие и не имеют встроенных средств обработки таймаута.

Для того, что бы организовать таймаут на подобных операциях, необходимо:

1. В начале программы, с помощью функции *signal()*, задать реакцию на
   сигнал SIGALRM
2. Непосредственно перед вызовом *getc()* задать значение таймаута функцией     *setitimer*
3. Непосредственно после вызова *getc()* сбросить таймаут.

Comment: Думаю, не корректно говорить, что getch() не существует, если ее нет в стандарте языка. В рамках conio.h она вполне себе существует :) Да, и можно чуть подробнее, что значит "сбросить таймаут"?

Comment: **что значит "сбросить таймаут"?** - когда обращаемся к *setitimer*, то передаём ей параметр типа *struct itimerval*. В этой структуре есть два поля, которые задают время до первого SIGALRM и интервал между последующими. Если оба значения обнулить, то это остановит генерацию сигналов - СБРОСИТ таймаут.

Answer (score 0):

Есть функция `kbhit()` которая проверяет наличие символа в клавиатурном буфере. Тогда Ваша программа будет выглядеть так

```c
char ch = 0;
while (!kbhit()) {
  if (timeout)
    break;
}
if (kbhit())
  ch = getch();
printf("Read char '%c'\n", ch);
```

Comment: Нууууу... `while (!kbhit())` — это холостой цикл, он гоняет процессор почём зря.